# Display value in bar chart when using iReport and JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jfreechart, bar-chart

We are designing reports using iReport 4.6.0..
Multiple bar charts and 3D bar charts have been used...But no matter what I do I am not able to display the individual value of the each bar either inside the bar or on top of the bar.
For both bar chart and 3D bar chart we are facing this problem..

The .jrxml file being generated from the ireport is being used in my application straight away to generate the report...

Anyone kindly guide on how to display value of each bar either inside the bar or on top of the bar..

Comment: I think the problem is that not many people (on here) are using iReport and JFreeChart.  The JFreeChart [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) includes several examples such as BarChartDemo5 but I'm not sure how this appled to iReport.

Answer (score 4):

If IReport "show label" option already checked then unchecked it and check again so that it works. Worked for me with IReport 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I also face with the same problem with you but I already solve it. First thing first, you must check 'Show Labels' option in chart properties. Then, what you need to do is try to make your bar chart in an appropriate size to allow the label shown at the top of each bar. If this way still not successful, try to explore using Chart Customizer and here is the link for your reference. Good luck..

http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/chart-customizers-1/

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when I try to create dynamic chart from java.I cant solve problem with using ***DJChart***.I use ***JFreeChart*** to see value of series part.And concatenate it with report.